# What is a simple and memory efficient algorithm for determining a link metric?

Tags: algorithm, networking, network-protocols, measurement, performance

I want to obtain a metric for the quality of a wireless link between two nodes.
The problem is, those nodes are not exchanging messages very often, but each message contains a time when the next message is scheduled to be send.

Currently, I'm using something like this:

```
if (message arrived in time)
    link_quality = link_quality/2 + 0.5
 else
    link_quality = link_quality/2
```

as suggested in rfc3626

Now link quality obviously changes a lot, a single lost packet will cut it in half. It is only used for hysteresis.

Assume there are two nodes, A and B. A's link_quality for B means how well it currently receives messages form B. It then announces `1 + link_quality * METRIC_MAX` (0 is invalid) to B, so B knows how well it can send messages to A.
Now the value A announces is subject to abrupt changes, so I've thought I'd do something like this

```
link_metric = (3 * link_metric + new_link_metric) / 4
```

Now this is slightly better, but it's still subject to a lot of fluctuation.
If I increase the 'weight' of the old value further, it will take quite a while before link_metric has a realistic value.

What would you suggest?

Comment: define 'quality'?  bandwidth, latency, jitter, packet loss?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you meant, your definition of quality it based on packet loss only.

you can try to give more weight to the old quality you measured:

```
n=<try some different weights to get the behavior of it>
if (message arrived in time)
    link_quality = ((n-1)*(link_quality)+1)/n
 else
    link_quality = ((n-1)*(link_quality)+0)/n
```

or you can try to use moving average (average of last N tries - equally weighted), to do this you need to store more data:

```
static int index
static int link_metrics[N]

link_quality-=(link_metrics[index]/N)
if (message arrived in time)
    link_metrics[index]=1
else
    link_metrics[index]=0
link_quality+=(link_metrics[index]/N)
index=(index+1)%N
```

And again play with N to see the behavior of this method.
This is a simple moving average there are more types of [MA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) you can try.